# Using CORS in Azure Storage to protect from illegal access of files

Tags: azure, cors, azure-storage

I have implemented SAS tokens to receive a video file from Azure Blob Storage. This all works fine. However, users are able to go to the developer console and retrieve the URL of the video (Which they will use to download illegally)

Most of the SO post suggest this cannot be done. However, I came across CORS in Azure storage. Will I be able to configure CORS to not allow request that doesn't originate from a particular host?

Can someone please let me know if its possible to protect illegal downloading of video files using CORS in Azure Storage ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please let me know if its possible to protect illegal
> downloading of video files using CORS in Azure Storage ?

No, CORS will not do that. [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) will only prevent your storage resources from cross-domain requests typically made via AJAX calls.

For example, let's say you have configured CORS rules to allow access to your storage blob from `mydomain.com`. An AJAX call originating from `mydomain.com` will be able to get the blob however an AJAX call originating from `otherdomain.com` will be rejected.

It does not prevent a user from copying the SAS URL of your blob and access that blob by pasting that URL in a browser. This request succeeds as it is not a cross-domain request.

Comment: Is there a workaround for my requirement which is to not allow users from copying URLs and accessing the content via a browser ?

Comment: One possibility is to use IP address restriction in your SAS token so that only requests originating from a particular IP address will be able to access your SAS URL. Other than that, the only option I could think of is downloading the blob in your web application and streaming its content from there.

Comment: Do you mean the IP address where the front end app is hosted ?

Comment: No, the client IP address.

Comment: ok, but still the user will be able to access the content. :(  I wonder how other companies (Like coursera ) protect its content

Comment: If the user gets access to the SAS token (even with the IP address specified) then they'll be still capable to download content from Azure storage. Yes. I too wonder how big businesses like Coursera, udemy protect its video courses.

Comment: `If the user gets access to the SAS token (even with the IP address specified) then they'll be still capable to download content from Azure storage.` - That's correct. `Yes. I too wonder how big businesses like Coursera, udemy protect its video courses.` - Not sure how they do it but you may want to look into `Azure Media Service` which is meant for delivering videos.